# Foreach loop echoing only one row from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is what my code does: when a username is typed in the `#type` input field, and if that typed value matches a row value from my database table `users`, then my jquery code will come to action. My jquery code will then reveal the hidden div that contains text of that typed in username. My problem is my current code ignores other typed in usernames, and for some reason will reveal only one username. Example of my issue:

```
 allen   <-- "allen" is typed in input field
--------
[allen]  <-- hidden div for allen now shows

 pete
-------- <-- "pete" is typed in input field
         <-- but hidden div for pete does not show. Why?
```

Is this an event bubbling issue with my js code? Because I did add e.propagation but it didn't do anything. How would I rewrite my current code so that *any username* that is typed will reveal a hidden div for it. Because currently I'm only able to get a hidden div for "allen" but not for the rest of the usernames. Please help, here is my code:

```
<input id="type">
<?php foreach (array_combine($userids, $usernames) as $userid => $username): ?>
<div id="border<?php echo $userid; ?>" style="display: none;">
    <input id="username<?php echo $userid; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" type="radio">
    <label for="username<?php echo $userid; ?>"><?php echo $username; ?></label>
</div>  
<?php endforeach; ?>

$("#type").on('input',function(){
    var userid = '<?php echo $userid; ?>';
    if (this.value == $("#username"+userid).attr('value')) {    
        $("#border"+userid).css("display", "block");
    }
    else {
        $("#border"+userid).css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Sql code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userid, username FROM usern");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $userids[] = $row['userid'];
  $usernames[] = $row['username'];
}
$stmt->close();
```

@MohammadBagheri - Output for code below:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userid, username FROM usern");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, 1).'</pre>';
}
$stmt->close();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [userid] => 35
    [username] => pete
)

Array
(
    [userid] => 44
    [username] => allen
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know what the problem is.

```
<input id="type">
<?php foreach (array_combine($userids, $usernames) as $userid => $username): ?>
<div id="border<?php echo $userid; ?>" style="display: none;">
    <input id="username<?php echo $userid; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" type="radio">
    <label for="username<?php echo $userid; ?>"><?php echo $username; ?></label>
</div>  
<?php endforeach; ?>

$("#type").on('input',function(){
    var username = $(this).val();
    var userid = $("input[value='"+username+"']").attr("id");

    $("div[id^=border]").css("display", "none");
    $("#border"+userid).css("display", "block");
});
```

You have been selecting the userid of the last occurrence of the loop and set that in jquery code which means it will always show the user with that user id and not checking what you input.

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @mohammedbagheri I greatly appreciate your help with this. But for some reason I am testing your script but it doesn't seem to work. Is it because my sql code is interfering with it? I edited my question and added my sql code.

Comment: @misner3456 Are you using PDO with mySql as the connection driver and database?

Comment: @mohammedbagheri Thanks for replying back. I'm not using PDO, I was using procedural mysqli to connect to the database. I'm also using phpmyadmin.

Comment: @misner3456 Could you please give me the output of the following code:




$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userid, username FROM usern");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, 1).'</pre>';
}
$stmt->close();

Comment: I am so sorry, I completely forgot about this question. I made an edit on my question to include the output of the code you just provided me. Thanks many for hanging onto this case